# How do I return json String jersey2.7

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I am using jersey 2.7

I want output as "{\"result\":1}"
I am getting output as {result:1}
I am using org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy and have added in web.xml

```
       <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

In rest controller

```
@POST
@Path("/start")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response start()
{
com.google.gson.JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("result",1);
return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject.toString()).build();

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a POJO? That's what MOXy is for.

Comment: I used pojo annotated with @XmlRootElement but I am getting same result

Comment: It should not be outputting `{result:1}`, but `{"result":1}`, which is how it _should_ output. What you want with with the back slashes, why would you want that?

Comment: I am using on javascript side to read the response as JSON.parse(data)

Comment: The backslashes and outer quotes should not be needed. Are you getting some kind of parsing error?

Comment: In javascipt console.log(data) ,I am getting Object {result: 1}  .while javascript is expecting string to be parsed back to json.

Comment: The data is already passed to your handler method as a Javascript object (not JSON), which should be the case with most JS frameworks. There's no need to parse it. Do console log `data.result`, it should print `1`

Comment: ok thanks,I thought sending and receiving encoded strings will be nice.ya ,data.result gives me 1